# Why can't phantomjs chain backbone methods?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine, phantomjs

I'm using Jasmine to test a backbone app, which works fine in the browser, but when I run it using grunt-contrib-jasmine via phantomjs it chokes on:

```
var myVar = myCollection.get('myModel').get('myAttribute');
```

which throws an error:

```
Testing jasmine specs via phantom
>> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'myCollection.get('myModel').get')
```

but the strange thing is this works just fine if I break it up like this:

```
var mdl = myCollection.get('myModel');
var myVar = mdl.get('myAttribute');
```

Is this a bug in phantom or am I missing something in the way I'm writing the code?

Seems like since it works in the browser it's a phantom problem.

Comment: Do you have a custom `get()` method on your collection by any chance?

Comment: @providencemac - I am interested to know why you ask this, what are you thinking it might be?

Comment: Nope, not using a custom get method.

Comment: @ekeren if the method was overridden it could have been changed to be async or have additional code paths that could return `undefined`. Since that's not the case it doesn't matter :)

Comment: @Jason perhaps the issue is not in the retrieval code that you've posted - it may be that the collection is not being populated with the model you're looking for... would you be able to post the full test case?

Comment: I will attempt to throw a test case together. I'm curious though, do you really think if that were the case that either a) breaking it up instead of chaining it would work? b) it would work in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be much bigger than I realize. It's rather complex to explain and frankly doesn't relate at all to this question. Consider this question dead.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, it would be nice if you could share what you found, even if the error is just the symptom for something else.

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but if I recall my model was all messed up.